# Switch Case error. Eclipse IDE for Android development on Mac : Change workspace compliance to JRE 1.7

Tags: android, eclipse, java

When trying to use a Switch Case with switch(string) for an android project , i get an error in eclipse IDE saying: Change workspace compliance to JRE1.7

Cannot switch on a value of type String for source level below 1.7. Only convertible int values or enum constants are permitted

When I change the project properties to 1.7, I get different error saying :

Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties

I dont want to change all those configuration strings to ENUMS. Do I have any other option?

My environment :
Eclipse SDK, Version: 3.7.2, Build id: M20120208-0800
OS : Mac SnowLeopard (10.6.8)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`JDK7` is not compatible with android so work with `JDK6`

`String` in `switch` was introduced in JDK7, so it will give an error in `JDK6`. You have to use either an `enum` or `if-elseif-else`.

So, change Java Compiler to `JDK6`.