# If one button press does something, other buttons pressed should do something else

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener, buttonclick

I have 5 Buttons in an activity. My code should work as follows :
1 (Correct) button pressed it should do something.
other 4 pressed, something else should be done... 
I don't want to used 5 onclicklistener

```
if(Button1 press) {
    do something
}

else if (button2 or button3 or button4 or button5 press)
{
    something else to do
}
```

Comment: Unless the buttons are very similar, I would really suggest using different on click listeners. It makes your code easier to read and understand when you come back to it in 6 months.

Comment: @GabeSechan if all `Buttons` but one do the same thing then using one listener is much easier to read and understand, IMHO. If they do different things then it gets confusing but here all but one do the same thing

Comment: Like I said-  unless they are very similar.  I just get tired of reading massive switch statements of doom that look like Windows message loops.

Comment: Fair enough...I agree with that. I'm just saying this particular situation is a perfect candidate for one listener and a `switch`

Answer (score 7):

Why don't you do it this way:

```
final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
final Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
final Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
final Button button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
final Button button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);

OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.equals(button1)) {
            // do something
        } else {
            // do something else
        }
    }
};

button1.setOnClickListener(listener);
button2.setOnClickListener(listener);
button3.setOnClickListener(listener);
button4.setOnClickListener(listener);
button5.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways to do it but if the same `buttons` will always do the same thing then you can set the `onClick(`) in your xml.

First, define the same function for each `Button`

```
<Button
     android:id="@+id/button1"
       ....
     android:onClick="functionName"/>
<Button
     android:id="@+id/button2"
       ....
     android:onClick="functionName"/>
```

then in your code

```
public void functionName(View v)
{
    switch (v.getId())   // v is the button that was clicked
    {
       case (R.id.button1):  // this is the oddball 
       ...do stuff
       break;
    default:   // this will run the same code for any button clicked that doesn't have id of button1 defined in xml
        ...do other stuff
    break;
    }
}
```

now your `Buttons` or `onClickListeners` don't have to be defined in your code unless you need to do something else with a `Button`

**Edit**

@prosperK has pointed out that with the newer ADT passing `int` to the `switch` causes errors so you may need an `if/else` if this is the case. [link to SO post about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10041414/switch-case-error-eclipse-ide-for-android-development-on-mac-change-workspace)

Comment: if OP is using newer ADT then switch-case caused error when we pass integer in switch case so if-else is better then switch-case. see  [Switch Case error. Eclipse IDE for Android development on Mac : Change workspace compliance to JRE 1.7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10041414/switch-case-error-eclipse-ide-for-android-development-on-mac-change-workspace)

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I did not realize that, thank you. I will edit. I was just about to ask for a link...thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You can define two different click listeners. Button 1 gets first listener and others get the second one. Hope this helps.